# PC suddenly powered off and won't power back on

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply

I have MSI B150m Mortar motherboard with Corsair 550w PSU, i5 6500 CPU, a 8GB kingston ram and a GTX 1060 GPU. Recently I had a external drive giving me problems, it was not being detected, so I bought a replacement for it, and in hopes of it getting detected so I can run 'ddrescue' on it, I was plugging and unplugging the drive back and forth while the OS was running, suddenly it powered off, and then it won't power back on. I tried to check all connections but nothing helped, I also tried to clear the BIOS by pressing and holding the reset button on the back of mobo, it turns on a blue LED on the mobo but still nothing happens.

Comment: Will it start in BIOS?  Shut down, start up and press F1 (or your BIOS key) repeatedly and see if BIOS setup comes up.

Comment: No nothing happens, as in no fan spins GPU also has white LED that is not showing even

Comment: This means the CPU is dead or possibly the PSU has failed.

Comment: Really? Is there a way to verify the problem?

Comment: If you have a voltmeter, try checking the outputs of the PSU to see if the problem is the PSU. If not, then CPU / Motherboard.

Comment: I think I do, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: You would need to look for test points on the main board.

Comment: I sent the PC to a repair shop, they said, some chip is dead, and the replacement is hard to find. Suggested to get a new motherboard.

Comment: So my second post was correct in that there was a significant hardware issue.

Comment: Yes, as of now I haven't decided on what I'm going to do, I asked the repair guy if he can find me a used motherboard replacement, as I don't want to spend money on a new one, because the processor is quite old now, 6 yrs almost, rather buy new system instead.